# rails resque and resque-send-later plugins causing "unitialized constant ClassName::Resque" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

i'm using the resque and resque-send-later PLUGINS (not gems) in my project.

I haven't put 'require' statements anywhere in the code at all (since they're plugins and so they must be included upon initialization).

the app is working perfectly locally, but on heroku, it shows an error
**"const_missing: unitialized constant User::Resque"**

my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Resque::Plugins::SendLater 

    def self.testingWorker1
        # code to be run in the background
    end
end
```

my User_controller: (where i'm calling the above method from)

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def testingResqueWorker
        User.send_later(:testingWorker1)
    end
end
```

so I removed the line include Resque::Plugins::SendLater from the my model
it still works perfectly locally, but now on heroku it gives an error saying **"method_missing: send_later"**

my question is:
1. how do we 'include' or 'require' plugins in rails? are they automatically available to all controllers and models?
2. any ideas for how to fix the above errors?

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts

- any reason why you aren't using the gems?
- are you sure the plugins have been added to the git repository and therefore have been deployed to heroku?